# Ruby on Rails calling ActiveRecord model from within ActionController plugin module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've a got a method in ActiveRecord::User:

```
def create_user_from_json(user)
  @user=User.new(user)
  if @user.save!
    @user.activate!
  end
end
```

And I'm trying to call it in a plugin's module method. The plugin is `json-rpc-1-1`. Here is the relevant code:

```
class ServiceController < ApplicationController
  json_rpc_service :name => 'cme',                        # required
  :id => 'urn:uuid:28e54ac0-f1be-11df-889f-0002a5d5c51b', # required
  :logger => RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER                         # optional

  json_rpc_procedure :name => 'userRegister',
  :proc => lambda { |u| ActiveRecord::User.create_user_from_json(u) },
  :summary => 'Adds a user to the database',
  :params => [{:name => 'newUser', :type => 'object'}],
  :return => {:type => 'num'}
end
```

The problem is the code in the `proc`. No matter whether I call `ActiveRecord::User.create_user_from_json(u)` or `::User.create_user_from_json(u)` or `User.create_user_from_json(u)` I just get `undefined method 'create_user_from_json'`.

What is the proper way to call a User method from the `proc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this needs to be a class method instead of an instance method, declare it like this:

```
def self.create_user_from_json(user)
  ...
end
```